# Why is this php code not working? (500 - Internal server error)

Tags: php

I do not know php at all. I have used the following code in a wordpress theme and it does not work. What's wrong with it?

ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE - returns en or ro (WPML)

```
<?php 
$lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
if ($lang == "en" ) {
   echo "L<span class="grey">ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>";
}
else { 
   echo "P<span class="grey">ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Your quotes in your echos need to be escaped. e.g. `echo "P<span class=\"grey\">...";` or replace your container quotes to single quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with double quotes.

Use single quotes so that you don't have to escape the double quotes (when using echo)

```
<?php
  $lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
  if ($lang == "en" ) {
     echo 'L<span class="grey">ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>';
  }
  else {
     echo 'P<span class="grey">ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>';
    } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes in a double quote string.

change your echo's to these :

```
echo "L<span class='grey'>ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
```

and

```
echo "P<span class='grey'>ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
```

(Notice the use of single quotes inside the double quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace doble quote arround "grey"
Try this:

```
<?php

            $lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;

             if ($lang == "en" ) {
                echo "L<span class='grey'>ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
             }
             else {
                echo "P<span class='grey'>ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
             } 



            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the usage of quotes ".

Change

```
             if ($lang == "en" ) {
                echo "L<span class='grey'>ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
             }
             else {
                echo "P<span class='grey'>ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class='grey'> slow fashion</span>";
             }
```

to

```
             if ($lang == "en" ) {
                echo "L<span class="grey">ocal Pioneer</span> <br /> in <span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>";
             }
             else {
                echo "P<span class="grey">ionier local </span> <br /> în<span class="grey"> slow fashion</span>";
             }
```